# error: ‘_1’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I'm trying to use **boost bind** in my ROS 2 package. But I'm getting the following error when building with *Colcon build*:

> error:‘_1’ was not declared in this scope

> error:‘ _2’ was not declared in this scope

Here is my C++ code:

```
 #include <functional>
 #include <memory>
 #include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
 #include "std_msgs/msg/string.hpp"
 #include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
 #include <message_filters/synchronizer.h>
 #include <message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h>
 #include <message_filters/time_synchronizer.h>
 #include "boost/bind/bind.hpp"
 #include <functional>

 void callback(const std_msgs::msg::String::SharedPtr& st_1, 
      const std_msgs::msg::String::SharedPtr& st_2) {
         // Callback function...
 }

 int main(int argc, char** argv){
     rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
     auto node = rclcpp::Node::make_shared("my_node");

     message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::msg::String> st_1(node, "st_1");
     message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::msg::String> st_2(node, "st_2");
     message_filters::TimeSynchronizer<std_msgs::msg::String, std_msgs::msg::String> sync(st_1, st_2, 10);
     sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&callback, _1, _2));

    rclcpp::spin(node);

    return 0;
 }
```

CMakeFile:

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
 project(project)

 # Default to C99
 if(NOT CMAKE_C_STANDARD)
     set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
 endif()

 # Default to C++14
 if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
 endif()

 if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
      add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
 endif()

 # find dependencies
 find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
 find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
 find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)
 find_package(message_filters REQUIRED)
 find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS 
      system
      filesystem 
      date_time 
      thread
 )

 if(BUILD_TESTING)
     find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
     ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
 endif()

 add_executable(sub src/subscriber.cpp)
 ament_target_dependencies(sub rclcpp std_msgs message_filters)
 target_include_directories(sub PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
 target_link_libraries(sub ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

 install(TARGETS
     sub
 DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})

 ament_package()
```

Any help is welcome! Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361017/error:-%E2%80%98_1%E2%80%99-was-not-declared-in-this-scope/) by [mirella melo](https://answers.ros.org/users/55539/mirella-melo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 194 on 2020-09-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As follows the changes I did in order to make it work:

Callback function:

```
  void callback(const std::shared_ptr<const std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void>>>& st_1,
               const std::shared_ptr<const std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void>>>& st_2){
  }
```

Main funcion:

```
   sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&callback, boost::placeholders::_1, boost::placeholders::_2));
```

---

Originally posted by [mirella melo](https://answers.ros.org/users/55539/mirella-melo/) with karma: 194 on 2020-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use `std::placeholders::_1`.  Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders.

This wasn't specifically asked, but will throw it out there anyway. In place of `boost::bind()`, you can use `std::bind()`

---

Originally posted by [surfertas](https://answers.ros.org/users/27828/surfertas/) with karma: 265 on 2020-09-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mirella melo](https://answers.ros.org/users/55539/mirella-melo/) on 2020-09-06**:
Thank you for answering me! Instead of using std, I kept with bind (I had tried your suggestion, but the usage is slightly different, got me confused, and I had new errors). Finally, I had some success with that. I'll let it as an answer as well. What is confusing me now is that:

`const std_msgs::msg::String::SharedPtr&` supposed to be the same as

`const std::shared_ptr<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void>>>&`

But the callback function only works with this extra 'const':

`const std::shared_ptr<const std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void>>>&`

Trying to figure out this...
Thanks once more!

**Comment by [surfertas](https://answers.ros.org/users/27828/surfertas/) on 2020-09-06**:
Sorry, I should have been more complete in my answer. Out of curiosity, why do you want to use the boost library when this particular case can all be completed using the standard library?

**Comment by [mirella melo](https://answers.ros.org/users/55539/mirella-melo/) on 2020-09-07**:
There is no specific reason... I was just following the tutorials. But after looking further, I found some differences between them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555566/difference-between-c11-stdbind-and-boostbind).